# regex woes when searching for spaces

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying, in vain, to create a regex string that accomplishes the following.

In any given string:
return true if the string is not made up of * and space characters.  So `**` is ok and `****   ****

  **` is fine (the \n may not have come through the editor)

but anything other than this needs to be flagged up.  Sometimes a string may be a single space or a series of space and line endings only, I'm having difficulty eliminating these.

I was working with `\\*+\\s+` but the check for single spacing is killing me

Comment: Just check for a [`[^ *]` (or `[^\s*]`)](https://regex101.com/r/mM3bL5/1) - if there is a match, flag this string. What is your programming environment? Also, maybe you need something like `^[ *]*[^ *]`?

Comment: Do you really code for iOS? I am asking because the *nsregularexpression* tag is commonly misused.

Comment: @null You've been here long enough to know about formatting, tagging and MCVE

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^[^* ]+$
```

Make sure you put the start "^" and end "$" anchors there

Comment: This won't match "   9* "

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, I am thinking the original question to be "I want to match strings that don't contain a * or a [space]"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Question says that string can only contain spaces and `*`, so of course `9` is not matched.

Comment: @MarkusLaire Wiktor isn't the original poster